# AngularJS - wrapping 3rd party asynchronic loaded library as a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a 3rd party library that loads to my page asynchronously and I would like to use it as a service.

How can I wrap the loading code inside an angular service? In general what would be the best practice?

At the moment my approach is something like so:

```
angular.module('myAPIServices', []).
factory('MyAPI', function () {
    return {
        \\ API is declared at the loaded script
        doStuff:function(){$window.API.doStuff()} 
    };
});
```

and then on the page outside of the Angular scope

```
(function () {
    var js = document.createElement('script');
    var loc = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "myAPI.js";
    loc.parentNode.insertBefore(js, loc);
}());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A posibility is to wrap your library call in [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q). This angular service returns a promise, which you can resolve when the library is fully loaded.

Your `doStuff` function would be something like:

```
doStuff: function() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   myAsyncCall().success(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
   });
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

In your controller you use the `then()` function to process the results.

A second possibility is with a callback. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7bNAd/) of both types.

If your library is manipulating the DOM, it is better to wrap it in a directive.

Comment: The examples on jsFiddle are awesome! Callback worked great for me.